# Serialization - differences between C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, serialization

I've recently been running some benchmarks trying to find the "best" serialization frameworks for C++ and also in Java.  The factors that make up "best" for me are
the speed of de/serializing and also the resulting size of the serialized object.

If I look at the results of various frameworks in Java, I see that the resulting byte[] is generally smaller than the object size in memory.  This is even the case with the built in Java serialization.  If you then look at some of the other offerings (protobuf etc.) the size decreases even more.

I was quite surprised that when I looked at things on the C++ size (boost, protobuf) that the resulting object is generally no smaller (and in some cases bigger) than the original object.

Am I missing something here?  Why do I get a fair amount of "compression" for free in Java but not in C++?

n.b for measuring the size of the objects in Java, I'm using Instrumentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

Comment: long getObjectSize(Object objectToSize)
Returns an implementation-specific approximation of the amount of storage consumed by the specified object. The result may include some or all of the object's overhead, and thus is useful for comparison within an implementation but not between implementations. The estimate may change during a single invocation of the JVM.

Answer (score 3):

Did you compare the absolute size of the data? I would say that Java has more overhead, so if you "compress" the data into a serialized buffer, the amount of overhead decreases a lot more. In C/C++ you have almost the bare minimum required for the physical data size, so there is not much room for compression. And in fact, you have to add additional information to deserialize it, which could even result in a growth.

Comment: I've updated the post to show how I'm measuring the object size in Java.  Do you mean that, it's not the serialization that's better in Java, it's the fact that the object representation in memory is far better in C++?

Comment: @imrichardcole, Yes, that's what I mean. You can dump the searialized object to a string and then compare the results to see what is really happening, as this is only my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Object size can be observed to be bigger than the actual data size due to the offset bits between data members.

When an object is serialized, these offset bits are discarded and as a result, serialized object memory is smaller.

Because java is a managed environment, it will need more of such offset data to control memory and ownership, therefore, their compression rate is bigger.